# How to add TableRow into Table dynamically?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

I'm trying to dynamically add Row in my table. But instead of adding Row, it just Updating my row value.

[image]

Json Response for Test.

```
{
  "EncPartnerId": "LEuT1eIlpLEMAAkZme3wpQ==",
  "EncTestId": "U4exk+vfMGrn7cjNUa/PBw==",
  "Fee": "100",
  "DiscountedFee": "80",
  "BookingFee": "50"
}
```

My API function by pressing `Add` button I trying to add Test Name with their data in my Table

```
   Future<void> GetTestFee() async {
var jsonResponse;
if (encTestId.isNotEmpty) {
  var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("http://myapitp.in/api/api/endpoint"),
      body: ({
        'EncPartnerId': encLabId,
        'EncTestId': encTestId,

      }));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("Correct");
    print(response.body);
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
    print(jsonResponse);
    getTestFeeObj=GetTestFeeMap.fromJson(jsonResponse);

  } else {
    throw Exception("Faild to fetch");
  }
} else {
  throw Exception("Faild to fetch");
}
return GetTestFee();

}
```

Then Printing it as DataTable.I  believe this not the correct approach. I also try to Create a empty list beforehand in the `build` method,`List<TableRow> tableRows = [];` but don't know how I can fill data in that list.

```
  SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: DataTable(
              columnSpacing: 13.0,
              columns: <DataColumn>[
                //DataColumn(label: Text("encPartnerId")),
                //DataColumn(label: Text("encTestId")),
                DataColumn(label: Text("TestName")),
                DataColumn(label: Text("Fee")),
                DataColumn(label: Text("Discounted Fee")),
                DataColumn(label: Text("Booking Fee")),
              ],
             rows: <DataRow>[
              DataRow(
                 cells: <DataCell>[
                // DataCell(Text(user?.encPartnerId ?? 'encPartnerId')),
                // DataCell(Text(user?.encTestId ?? 'encPartnerId')),
                DataCell(Container(child: Text(testName?? '',overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis))),
                DataCell(Text(getTestFeeObj?.fee ?? '')),
                DataCell(Text(getTestFeeObj?.discountedFee ?? '')),
                DataCell(Text(getTestFeeObj?.bookingFee ?? '')),
               ],
              )
             ]
             ),
          )
```

Comment: Your array that you pass to `rows` is currently hardcoded to be a single `DataRow`. If you want it to display more rows, you need to programmatically generate the additional rows.

Comment: Yeah I managed to rectify it .Thanks to people like you in DevCommunity! I took a empty ArrayList[], every time adding item to this array when Im calling my API, and in table I just Map to those item.

Comment: @Abion47 you should post the answer as an answer and Toujo should mark it as correct so that other people do waste time trying to answer an already solved problem

Comment: Alright! I will answer my own question here.

Answer (score 0):

Json Response

```
 {
  "EncPartnerId": "LEuT1eIlpryry",
  "EncTestId": "U4exk+vfMyry",
  "Fee": "100",
  "DiscountedFee": "80",
  "BookingFee": "50"
 }
```

My JSON response Model class

```
  class GetTestFeeMap { // Need this class
  String? encPartnerId;
  String? encTestId;
  int? fee;
  int? discountedFee;
  int? bookingFee;

  GetTestFeeMap(
      {this.encPartnerId,
      this.encTestId,
      this.fee,
      this.discountedFee,
      this.bookingFee});

  GetTestFeeMap.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    encPartnerId = json['EncPartnerId'];
    encTestId = json['EncTestId'];
    //fee = json['Fee'];
    fee = int.parse(json['Fee']);
    // discountedFee = json['DiscountedFee'];
    discountedFee = int.parse(json['DiscountedFee']);
    //bookingFee = json['BookingFee'];
    bookingFee = int.parse(json['BookingFee']);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['EncPartnerId'] = this.encPartnerId;
    data['EncTestId'] = this.encTestId;
    data['Fee'] = this.fee;
    data['DiscountedFee'] = this.discountedFee;
    data['BookingFee'] = this.bookingFee;
    return data;
  }
}
```

- I took a empty List[] in `state`

  `List<GetTestFeeMap> reponseArray = [];` // Storing API response || later showing test fee in table format
- After getting API response add it into list

  ```
   var response = await http.post(
     Uri.parse("http://ytyttiiiuiu.in/api/myapi/GetTestFee"),
     body: ({
       'EncPartnerId': encLabId,
       'EncTestId': encTestId
       }));
   if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("Correct");
     print(response.body);
     jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
     print(jsonResponse);

     getTestFeeObj=GetTestFeeMap.fromJson(jsonResponse);
     reponseModel.add(getTestFeeObj) // Here adding my response to list[]
  ```

Then mapping those data in my DataTable

```
 child: DataTable(
                  columnSpacing: 13.0,
                  columns: <DataColumn>[
                    DataColumn(label: Text("Fee")),
                    DataColumn(label: Text("Discounted Fee")),
                    DataColumn(label: Text("Booking Fee")),
                  ],
                  rows: reponseArray.map((testRowData) {
                    return DataRow(cells: [
                      DataCell(Text(testRowData.fee!.toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(testRowData.discountedFee!.toString())),
                      DataCell(Text(testRowData.bookingFee!.toString()))
                    ]);
                  }).toList()),
```